# Any examples of Flot with some infoboxes?

Tags: jquery, flot

I have jQuery Flot Pie chart and i need to show some links in info-box/tool-tip when clicking on the chart element. Is there some already invented thing for?

Comment: See official examples here: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html, you'll want to change the `plothover` binding to a `$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {`.  Get that working, come back if you have specific questions...

Answer (score 2):

The last point from the [example page](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-pie/index.html) for the pie chart should get you started. The chart is initialized with:

```
$.plot('#placeholder', data, {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    }
});
```

Than you can bind handlers to the `plotclick` event (again from the example page):

```
placeholder.bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, obj) {
    if (!obj) {
        return;
    }

    percent = parseFloat(obj.series.percent).toFixed(2);
    alert(""  + obj.series.label + ": " + percent + "%");
});
```

This example brings up an alert box, it shouldn't be to hard to change that to what you desire. The `plothover` and `plotclick` events are explained in the [Customizing the grid](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You must first setup your plot to be hoverable and clickable.

```
$.plot('#placeholder', data, {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true
        }
    }, 
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
         clickable: true
   }
});
```

Following this, you may want to try something like this. Make a global variable named

```
previousPoint = null.
```

This function creates a div that is appended to the body of the html. You can adjust the styling however you like.

```
function showToolTip(x, y, contents) {
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y - 25,
        left: x + 5,
        padding: '2px',     
        size: '10',   
        'border-radius': '6px 6px 6px 6px',
        'background-color': '#F8E397',
        opacity: 0.80
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}

$.fn.useToolTip = function (){
    $(this).bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item){                         
        if (item)
        { 
           if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) 
           {
              previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
              $("#tooltip").remove();
              var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2);   //I believe x and y will still 
                                                      //work on a pie chart because 
                                                      //they do not refer to 
                                                      //coordinates, but rather, they 
                                                      //refer to the position of the 
                                                      //graph your mouse is hovering.
              var y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);    
              showToolTip(item.pageX, item.pageY, "whatever text you would like to display");
              }
           }
           else
           {
              $("#tooltip").remove();
              previousPoint = null;
           }
    });
};
```

You call the function after you have plotted your data like this:

```
$("#placeholder").useToolTip();
```